# the logic of numeral systems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, education, math-history, number-systems

i have a question about numeral systems that use the place value concept ,                                 in the decimal system the position is a power of ten and it has set of ten unique digits, the binary system its  position is a power of two and it has a set of two unique digits and so on for all systems that use the place value concept
my question is why the position value depends in the number of digits ?                                  why cant we have a system that has n unique digits and use a position value different than n let's say m for example ?

Comment: You can write numbers any way you like, though I can't follow the method you sketch.

Comment: Whatever system you use , you need more digits if the numbers get larger. No idea how you want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying some examples and seeing which number representations you get.

If $n<m$, then some numbers will not be representable (e.g. in base 10 with digits up to 8, you can't represent the number 19). If $n>m$, then some numbers will have multiple representations (e.g. "3" and "11" in base 2). The only way to ensure every number has a unique representation is for the number of digits to match the position value.